# Using onSaveInstanceState With Multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities in my application.

From the first one i started the second, and from the second i started the third. When the process of my app is killed by the system and i launch it again i see only the last active activity is being created. And it seems the only one that gets Bundle object as a parameter to its onCreate method.

There are two things I am curious of:

- If the activity at the top of the stack is the only one that gets its bundle, why each of my activities got their callback (onSaveInstanceState) called just before their onStop() method.
- If only one of my activities can retain original state, what about the others? Did they lose all their state just because system decided to kill my app process? Should i restore them manually? What about views on them? (normally views get their state back without needing me to put something into the bundle and later restore if i am not mistaken)

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is this (tested on 4.1.1):

- When you start a new activity, `onSaveInstanceState` of the previous activity is being called
- When the system kills the app, the state of activities back-stack is being saved
- When you restart the app, the last seen activity is being shown and its `onRestoreInstanceState` is being called
- When you navigate back and pop activities from the back stack, state of each of them will be restored with a call to `onRestoreInstanceState` passing the bundle that was obtained from the first step above.

Therefore, the answers to your questions are:

1. All activities will be restored, but not at once - the last one seen is restored immediately, while the others will be restored when you navigate back.
2. All simple views (e.g. EditText) will automatically restore their state. In order for this to happen, you need to make sure that a) you did not override `onSaveInstanceState` or `onRestoreInstanceState` without call to `super` implementations b) the views that should be restored have unique IDs in view hierarchy

Comment: So, the only case that the activity's `onStop` is getting called without `onSavedInstanceState` is hitting the 'Back' button or calling `finish` on the activity?

Answer (score 0):

onStop is called on previous activity when you create a new activity, so you are saving the state! Your previous activity's onCreate will be called, if it's destroyed, so don't worry about recreating views.  Are you sure app is killed? An app is not killed when it loses view. Android will keep it in memory as long as it doesn't need to free memory.